# Fetch and display multiple rows and columns from mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

This is my database table:

[image: Database table]

I want to display this table (5 columns) on my page when clicking a button (List Users).

But I'm getting the following as output:

[image: Output table]

My code is:

```
<?php
$db = "*";  //masked for security
$host = "*"; //masked for security
$user = "*";//masked for security
$pwd = "*; //masked for security
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pwd,$db);
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

$sql="SELECT login_id,user_name,password,user_role,status_id FROM login";
$select = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($select);
echo "Number of rows : ";
echo $num_rows;
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($select, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Login ID</th>
<th>User name</th>
<th>Password</th>
<th>User Role</th>
<th>Status ID</th>
</tr>";

foreach ($row as $rows)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $rows['login_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $rows['user_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $rows['password'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $rows['user_role'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $rows['status_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Please help me find the error in this code.

Comment: once print_r($row) this and check what exactly you are getting

Comment: Its hurting my brain to see `foreach ($row as $rows)` instead of `foreach($rows as $row)`. But seriously, do what @RahulMeshram says so we can see what we are working with.

Comment: Could You Please Add print_r in your for each loop and send us the result again ?

Comment: what's the point of `foreach` loop there if you getting only one row with `mysqli_fetch_array` ? You should use `while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($select, MYSQLI_ASSOC) { ... }`

Comment: @RahulMeshram  http://imgur.com/a/pccEv

Comment: Why is it displaying the data of only one row 4 times?

Comment: see your mistake now? You looping same row as many times as it has columns

Comment: Follow steps from this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php). It should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you getting only one row with `mysqli_fetch_array($select, MYSQLI_ASSOC);`
you should loop through results

`while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($select, MYSQLI_ASSOC) { 
    your code here
   ... 
}`

now if `foreach` loop you going through same row as many times as it has columns.

Answer (score 1):

you have mistake some condition so use this code which will work, only `while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($select, MYSQLI_ASSOC))` will work for listing data so no need double loop

```
<?php
$db = "*";  //masked for security
$host = "*"; //masked for security
$user = "*";//masked for security
$pwd = "*"; //masked for security
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $db);
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

$sql = "SELECT login_id,user_name,password,user_role,status_id FROM login";
$select = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($select);
echo "Number of rows : ";
echo $num_rows;

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Login ID</th>
<th>User name</th>
<th>Password</th>
<th>User Role</th>
<th>Status ID</th>
</tr>";
if ($num_rows > 0) {

    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($select, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $rows['login_id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $rows['user_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $rows['password'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $rows['user_role'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $rows['status_id'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

for more information

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp